# QThread, AttributeError: 'MyThread' does not have a signal with the signature signal()

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qthread

Код:

```
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal

class MyThread(QThread):
    signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.signal.connect(self.tock)

    def run(self):
        starttime=time.time()
        while True:
            print("tick")
            self.signal.emit()
            time.sleep(1)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def tock(self):
        print("tock")

thread = MyThread()
thread.start()
```

Ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual \studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd_vendored\pydevd_pydev_bundle\pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 192, in _new_run
> return self._original_run()
> File "C:\Users\User\source\repos\PyTest\PyTest\PyTest.py", line 17, in run
> self.signal.emit()
> AttributeError: 'MyThread' does not have a signal with the signature signal()

В чём причина этой ошибки и как её исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
thread = MyThread()
thread.start()
```

на

```
self.thread = MyThread()
self.thread.start()
```

---

```
import sys
#import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal

class MyThread(QThread):

    signal = pyqtSignal(str)                  # + str

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pass

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.signal.emit("tick")
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(1000)


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.textEdit   = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start MyThread")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.startMyThread)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)  

    def startMyThread(self):  
        self.thread = MyThread()
        self.thread.signal.connect(self.tock)
        self.thread.start()        

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def tock(self, text):
#        print(text)
        self.textEdit.append(text)        

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    window = ExampleApp()  
    window.show()  
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]